# How do I properly bind the CommandParameter with my ContextMenu to the selected ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, command

So I have a `ListView`, and when I right-click a item in there I have a command setup that fires when clicking.
I want to be able to get the text that's inside the the selected item.
So I guess I want to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListView` as the `CommandParameter`

I've noticed that the `ContextMenu` is not in the visual tree which makes things a bit more confusing.

It's currently returning `null`

```
<ListView x:Name="PlayerListView"
                  Width="200"
                  Height="330"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="0,80,15,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Background="#252525"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ServerViewModel.Players}">


            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:PlayerModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="190"
                                Background="#222222">

                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Command One"
                                          DataContext="{Binding DataContext, 
                                          Source={mvvm:RootObject}}" 
                                          Command="{Binding ServerViewModel.MyCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu},
                                            Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="../../Assets/image.png"
                                               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
/>
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                        <Image Source="../../Assets/image.png"
                               Width="20"
                               Height="20"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" 
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Margin="5"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The command is working fine, everything is firing but it returns null, and I know it's because how the XAML is setup, but I am not sure how to traverse through the DOM

DataContext is setup like this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
}
```

The RelayCommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ObservableObject, ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {

        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //This is where I debug and see that it returns null
            _execute.Invoke(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the the `PlacementTarget` (`StackPanel`) of the `ContextMenu` and then get its `DataContext`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:PlayerModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Width="190"
                Background="#222222"
                Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Command One"
                        Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ServerViewModel.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="../../Assets/image.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

        <Image Source="../../Assets/image.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" 
                Foreground="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```